# Why am I getting connection error on calling notify on Azure SignalR

Tags: azure, signalr

I have configured a SignalR resource on my Azure account and am sending a message to the SignalR Hub using the below snippet in an Azure Function written in C#:

```
await signalRMessages.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage()
            {
                Target = "notify",
                Arguments = new object[] { requestBody }
            });
```

However, I keep getting the below error.

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I have also verified that the Azure function URL for negotiate function returns me the below information as expected.

{"endpoint":"https://xxxxxxx.service.signalr.net:5001/client/?hub=broadcast","accessKey":"yyyyyyy"}

Why am I getting the connection error and what could I change in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This error means no server listening at specified ip/port that you are trying to connect to. It can be caused by using the wrong IP address or the wrong [PORT](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/372).